# Drop down menu current page

Tags: jquery

I have drop down menu and so far i made something like this

```
$(function() {
    // hide all the sub-menus
    $("span.toggle").next().hide();
    $(".current").parents("li ul").show();

    // add a link nudging animation effect to each link
    $("#jQ-menu a, #jQ-menu span.toggle").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            //paddingLeft:"10px",
            color:"black"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            paddingLeft:"0",
            color:"#808080"
        }, 300);
    });

    // set the cursor of the toggling span elements
    $("span.toggle").css("cursor", "pointer");

    // prepend a plus sign to signify that the sub-menus aren't expanded
    $("span.toggle").prepend("+ ");
    // add a click function that toggles the sub-menu when the corresponding
    // span element is clicked
      $("span.toggle").click(function() {

            $(this).next().toggle(1000);
                // switch the plus to a minus sign or vice-versa
                var v = $(this).html().substring( 0, 1 );
                if ( v == "+" ){
                    $(this).html( "-" + $(this).html().substring( 1 ) );
                    var li = $(this).parent().siblings('li');
                    $('span.toggle', li).each(function(){
                        var v = $(this).html().substring( 0, 1 );
                        if ( v == "-" ){
                        $(this).html( "+" + $(this).html().substring( 1 ) );
                        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
                        }
                    });
                } else if ( v == "-" )
                    $(this).html( "+" + $(this).html().substring( 1 ) );
        });
    });
```

I want to make my menu expand on a current page. Now it is but "+" is replaced with "-" when it is expanded (it should be "-") Also when both ("Pierwsze" and "Drugie") are expanded and when i close on "Pierwsze" then also "drugie" is closing. But when i have both closed and i click "Drugie" to expand then "Pierwsze" is also expanding. By the way i want when "pierwsze" ius expanded and then i click on "Drugie" then "Pierwsze" should be closed.
Sorry for my english. I hope i described it properly. I don't know how to do that drop down menu to work good.
Here is link http://jsbin.com/amofoz/11/edit

Comment: don't link the code...please edit your question to include the code in your question from jsbin....

Comment: @pinkpanther - what? AFAIK no problem with linking, as long as it's clean, specific, and follows one-question-one-answer format.

Comment: @Beneczek - hi and welcome to SO :)

Comment: @Steve but is it ok if link is broken in future?

Comment: @pinkpanther - good point, but that's a long row to hoe...wonder if there's anything on meta about that.

Comment: I added code and also a link to jsbin. :)

Comment: @pinkpanther - I stand corrected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code sez `when you see a question like this, vote down, and vote to close`. Wowzers.

Comment: Can anyone help? I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsbin.com/amofoz/27/

I've changed this:

```
 $('span.toggle', li).each(function(){
```

to this:

```
$(this).find('span.toggle', li).each(function(){
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hmm it helps a lot but still there are replaced "+" and "-" and i need it when "Pierwsze" is open and i click "Drugie" i want "pierwsze" to be closed. :)